# SQLite.Net SQLiteException Constraint insert

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sqlite.net

I'm using SQLite.Net within a Xamarin Android application. I have an entity which looks like this:

```
[DataEntity]
public class AuditEntity
{
        [PrimaryKey]
        public Guid EntryId { get; set; }

        public string Action { get; set; }        
        public string GeoLocation { get; set; }        
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

I have a generic insert method which looks like this:

```
public int Insert<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
                var result = 0;

                try
                {                
                    result = Connection.Insert(obj);                
                }
                catch (SQLiteException ex)
                {               
                    Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, $"Exception while inserting into database:\r\n{ex.ToLongString()}");
                }

                return result;
}
```

I pass the following object into this method:

```
var auditEntry = new AuditEntity
{
                EntryId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Action = uri.ToString(),
                GeoLocation = geoLocation,
                Time = DateTime.Now
};
```

Occasionally a SQLite exception is thrown with a message of "Constraint", which I understand is a violation of the primary key.

The EntryId column in the (automatically created) table is of type varchar(36).

Why would the insert sometimes throw the exception?

If I use a non-generic method, that does the insert via a parameterised command, I do not see the exception, but I'd rather use the generic method.

Comment: which sql.net dll you used? I have tried the [SQLite Component](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite-component/) in xamarin android. Did not find the `Connection.insert(obj)` method.

Comment: We're using https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: Do you have another entity type with similar properties? If so, the connection could be mistaking which table to insert to.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. We have other entities which use a Guid as a primary key, but with a different property name e.g. "LogID". Some also have a "Time" property. I see an overload of the Insert method takes a "type" parameter. I'll use that overload and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Using the overload didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In above code 'EntryId' is set as a auto incremented column, So you don't need to insert the 'EntryId' value again and you can set datatype of 'EntryId' is integer.

If you want guid type of id, You can set EntryId = Guid.NewGuid().Tostring() in your entity Then every new value inserted in your table automatically create the entryId.(I have not much reputation to comment your question, so I have ping in form of answer.)

Comment: Your answer is not correct. If I don't specify the ID on the object to be inserted, the value stored in the database in an uninitialised Guid. I also don't want to change the type of the ID from Guid to string; Guid is the correct type.